# New to registries/repositories and trying to figure out my registry destination address

Tags: docker, url, repository, registry, push

I'm trying to push a SAS image to a free local jfrog docker and can't figure out the registry url. The artifacts page lists 'URL to file:
[https://machinewars.jfrog.io/artifactory/sasdocker/'](https://machinewars.jfrog.io/artifactory/sasdocker/%27) but when I try this url I get the error:

Error: failed to start upload for "https://machinewars.jfrog.io/v2/artifactory/sasdocker/viya-4-x64_oci_linux_2-docker/sas-transfer/blobs/uploads/" 404 404 Not Found

--destination registry-location
Specifies the host name and repository path of the registry to which images are replicated. Here is an example:
registry.example.com/my-project

Answer (score 0):

Container image registries cannot be served on a context path. Valid registry urls:

```
https://docker.io
https://quay.io
https://myregistry.mydomain.com
https://foo.bar.com:8443
```

Invalid registry urls:

```
https://myregistry.mydomain.com/mypath
https://machinewars.jfrog.io/artifactory
```

This is because container images can contain `/` on their name. If serving registries in a different context path was allowed it would not be possible for your container client to differentiate between an image name and a path in a url.